# Does $\int_0^{\infty } \cos \left(e^x\right) \, dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus

So, there he is $$\int_0^{\infty } \cos \left(e^x\right) \, dx$$

Mathematica says it is a convergent integral, but I need some sort of a proof. How do we know that it is actually convergent? 
I've tried to prove that it is convergent with Abel's and Dirichlet's test...and here I am. 
Any help?

Comment: Have you tried substituting $u=e^x$?

Comment: See [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Integrate by parts, letting $u=e^{-x}$ and $dv=e^x\cos(e^x)\,dx$.

We arrive at an obviously convergent integral.

**Remarks:** $1.$ It is reasonable (but as we saw not necessary) to make the preliminary change of variable $t=e^x$. Then we arrive at the integral
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}{t}\,dt\tag{1}.$$
If we already *know*, from prior work, that this integral converges, then we are finished. But if we don't, we have to attack that problem, perhaps by integration by parts (there are other techniques). Note that it is not immediate that the integral (1) converges. Our function has absolute value $\le \frac{1}{t}$, but that is not useful, since $\int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{t}$ *diverges*.

$2.$ You may be expected to operate at a higher level of formality, by showing that
$$\lim_{B\to\infty} \int_0^B \cos(e^x)\,dx$$
exists.

Comment: And then I have $$ \int_1^{\infty } \frac{\cos (u)}{u} \, du$$

Comment: This is bounded by $\pi$ times the sum of the alternating series, or something

Comment: $du=-e^{-x}\,dx$ and $v=\sin(e^x)$. We end up with a nicely behaved first term, and $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sin(e^x)\,dx$, which converges since $|\sin(e^x)|\le 1$.

Comment: This integral is convergent since a)cosine of u is a bounded function and b)1/u converges to zero. Am I right?

Comment: I prefer the way I put it, since after all the integral $\int_1^\infty  \frac{dw}{w}$ diverges. But there is clearly no issue with $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sin(e^x)\,dx$, since $e^{-x}$ goes to $0$ fast.

Comment: Oh, now I see the point

Comment: Integrate by parts (after the substitution).